# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "stat.dpndcyDt"

Tags: angular

There are a few posts of this subject on the site, but they all say to import FormsModule, which I believe I have done.

app.shared.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...

    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        FormsModule,
        ...
    ]
})
```

component.html

```
<input required type="date" name="Date-{{in}}" class="form-control" [ngModel]="stat.dpndcyDt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="stat.dpndcyDt=$event" #TESTX="stat.dpndcyDt" />
```

Is there something else that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with `#TESTX="stat.dpndcyDt"`.

If it's a component of yours, remove it to correct it (see why below), and if it's a test, remove it too.

This syntax makes Angular expect to have either a directive or a component with `exportAs: 'stat.dpndcyDt'` in their decorator.

Comment: Major case of the Mondays... I just needed to change it to

#Date="ngModel"

Well i guess the #Date part was not the problem, but that was the way I had intended to name it.  TESTX was as you imagine, just from experimenting why it wasn't working.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark your answer as resolved, either with my answer or your own !

Comment: It made me wait a few minutes to mark it resolved, you answered too quickly :-D